# Построения графика заданной функции e^x*x^3

Tags: c#, winforms

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать задачу. К сожалению, мало что в этом не понимаю.
график ф-ции y=x^2+1 на интервале [-3,5]

---

```
namespace Function
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBoxFunction.Image = new Bitmap(pictureBoxFunction.Width, pictureBoxFunction.Height);
            Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBoxFunction.Image);

            gr.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1), new Point(20, 560), new Point(420, 560));
            for (int i = 40, j = -8; i < 420; i += 20, j++)
            {
                gr.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1), new Point(i, 555), new Point(i, 565));
                if (j != 0)
                gr.DrawString(j.ToString(), DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(i-5, 567));
            }

            gr.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1), new Point(200, 20), new Point(200, 610));
            for (int i = 40, j = 26; i < 601; i += 20, j--)
            {
                gr.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1), new Point(195, i), new Point(205, i));
                if(j != 0)
                gr.DrawString(j.ToString(), DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(207, i-5));
            }

            gr.DrawString(">  X", DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(415, 553), new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoClip));
            gr.DrawString("<", DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(192, 17), new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical));
            gr.DrawString("Y", DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(195, 5));

            Point[] p = new Point[9];
            for (int i = -3, j = 0; i < 6; i++, j++)
                p[j] = new Point(200 + i * 20, (i * i * (-20) + 560 - 1 * 20));
            gr.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            gr.DrawCurve(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 1), p);
        }

        private void pictureBoxFunction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Как переделать на эту функцию?
график ф-ции e^x*x^3 на интервале X[-6;2] Y[-2;10]

Comment: Что именно вы в этом не понимаете и как вам можно помочь понять? Еще у вас стоит тег WPF, а код вы показываете из Windows Forms.

Comment: @aepot исправил тег на winforms.
Не знаю как этот код передалать на эту ф-цию e^x*x^3 на интервале X[-6;2] Y[-2;10]

Comment: @Bohdan Начните в таком случае с [этого](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/graphics-and-drawing-in-windows-forms) и [этого](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.math?view=netframework-4.8).